# Naive convex hull from Algorithms in a Nutshell book

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, rust

I am working through the book Algorithms in a Nutshell by George T. Heineman and trying to translate the pseudocodes into Rust.

Here is a naive convex hull algorithm:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering::Equal;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::ops::{Add, Sub, Mul}; 
use std::collections::BTreeSet;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Point {
    x: f64, 
    y: f64, 
}


impl PartialEq for Point {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Point) -> bool {
        if self.x.is_nan() & other.x.is_nan() & self.y.is_nan() & other.y.is_nan() {
            return true;
        }
        if self.x.is_nan() & other.x.is_nan() {
            return self.y == other.y; 
        }
        if self.y.is_nan() & other.y.is_nan() {
            return self.x == other.x;
        }
        (self.x == other.x) & (self.y == other.y)
    }
}


impl Eq for Point {}

impl PartialOrd for Point {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Point) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}



impl Ord for Point {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Point) -> Ordering {
        let c = self.x.partial_cmp(&other.x).unwrap();
        if c == Equal {
            self.y.partial_cmp(&other.y).unwrap()
        } else {
            c
        }
    }
}


impl Point {
    pub fn new(x: f64, y: f64) -> Point {
        if x.is_nan() | y.is_nan() {
            panic!("Coordinates cannot be NaN!");
        }
        Point {
            x: x,
            y: y,
        }
    }

    // Euclidean distance
    fn distance(&self, other: &Point) -> f64 {
        ((self.x - other.x).powi(2) + (self.y - other.y).powi(2)).sqrt()
    }

    // Draw a horizontal line through this point, connect this point with the other, and measure the angle between these two lines. 
    fn angle(&self, other: &Point) -> f64 {
        (other.y - self.y).atan2(other.x - self.x)
    }
}

impl Add for Point {
    type Output = Point; 
    fn add(self, rhs: Point) -> Point {
        Point::new(self.x + rhs.x, self.y + rhs.y)
    }
} 
impl Sub for Point {
    type Output = Point; 
    fn sub(self, rhs: Point) -> Point {
        Point::new(self.x - rhs.x, self.y - rhs.y)
    }
} 
// dot product 
impl Mul for Point {
    type Output = f64; 
    fn mul(self, rhs: Point) -> f64 {
        self.x * rhs.x + self.y * rhs.y
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_point() {
    use std::f64::consts::PI; 
    let p1 = Point::new(0.0, 0.0); 
    let p2 = Point::new(0.0, 1.0); 
    assert_eq!(p1.angle(&p2), PI/2.0);
    assert_eq!(p1.distance(&p2), 1.0);
    let p1 = Point::new(0.0, 0.0); 
    let p2 = Point::new(1.0, 1.0); 
    assert_eq!(p1.angle(&p2), PI/4.0);
    assert_eq!(p1.distance(&p2), 2.0f64.sqrt());
    let p1 = Point::new(0.0, 0.0); 
    let p2 = Point::new(1.0, -1.0); 
    assert_eq!(p1.angle(&p2), -PI/4.0);
    assert_eq!(p1.distance(&p2), 2.0f64.sqrt());
}

#[derive(PartialEq,Eq,Debug)]
struct Triangle {
    p0: Point, 
    p1: Point, 
    p2: Point,
}

impl Triangle {
    fn new(p0: Point, p1: Point, p2: Point) -> Triangle {
        // Sort by x-coordinate to make sure the first point is the leftmost and lowest.
        let mut v: Vec<Point> = vec![p0, p1, p2];
        v.sort();
        Triangle {
            p0: v[0], 
            p1: v[1], 
            p2: v[2],
        }
    }

    fn range_x(&self) -> (f64, f64) {
        (self.p0.x, self.p2.x)
    }
    fn range_y(&self) -> (f64, f64) {
        let mut v = vec![self.p0, self.p1, self.p2];
        v.sort_by(|a, b| {
            a.y.partial_cmp(&(b.y)).unwrap_or(Equal)
        });
        (v[0].y, v[2].y)
    }

    // Barycentric Technique, check whether point is in triangle, see http://blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/
    fn contains(&self, p: Point) -> bool {
        let v0 = self.p2 - self.p0; 
        let v1 = self.p1 - self.p0; 
        let v2 = p - self.p0; 
        let dot00 = v0 * v0; 
        let dot01 = v0 * v1;
        let dot02 = v0 * v2;
        let dot11 = v1 * v1;
        let dot12 = v1 * v2;
        let inv_denom = 1.0f64 / (dot00 * dot11 - dot01 * dot01);
        let u = (dot11 * dot02 - dot01 * dot12) * inv_denom;
        let v = (dot00 * dot12 - dot01 * dot02) * inv_denom;
        (u > 0.0) & (v > 0.0) & (u + v < 1.0)
    }
}


#[macro_export]
macro_rules! btreeset {
    ($($x: expr),*) => {{
         let mut set = ::std::collections::BTreeSet::new();
         $( set.insert($x); )*
         set
    }}
}

pub fn convex_hull_naive(points: &BTreeSet<Point>) -> BTreeSet<Point> {
    // you must have at least 3 points, otherwise there is no hull 
    assert!(points.len() > 2);
    // a fn for removing just one point from the set
    let minus_one = |p: &Point| {
        points.difference(&(btreeset!(p.clone()))).cloned().collect::<BTreeSet<Point>>()
    };
    // set of points that are marked as internal
    let mut p_internal_set: BTreeSet<Point> = BTreeSet::new();
    // check permutations of 4 points, check if the fourth point is contained in the triangle
    for p_i in points {
        let minus_i = minus_one(&p_i);
        for p_j in &minus_i {
            let minus_j = minus_one(&p_j);
            for p_k in &minus_j {
                let minus_k = minus_one(&p_k);
                for p_m in &minus_k {
                    if Triangle::new(p_i.clone(), p_j.clone(), p_k.clone()).contains(p_m.clone()) {
                        p_internal_set.insert(p_m.clone());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // set of points that are not internal
    let mut hull = points.difference(&p_internal_set).cloned().collect::<Vec<Point>>();
    // sort by coordinates so that the first point is the leftmost
    hull.sort();
    let head = hull[0].clone();
    let angle_to_head = |p: &Point| {
        if p == &head {
            0.0
        } else {
            head.angle(p)
        }
    };
    // sort by the angle with the first point 
    // when that is equal, sort by distance to head
    hull.sort_by(|a, b| {
        let angle_a = angle_to_head(&a);
        let angle_b = angle_to_head(&b);
        angle_a.partial_cmp(&angle_b).unwrap()
    });
    hull.into_iter().collect::<BTreeSet<Point>>()
//  return vec![Point::new(1.0, 1.0)];
}

#[test]
fn test_convex_hull_naive() {
    let points = (0..4).into_iter().flat_map(move |i| {
        let i = i as f64;
        (0..4).into_iter().map(move |j| {
            let j = j as f64;
            Point::new(i, j)
        })  
    }).collect::<BTreeSet<Point>>();
//  let mut points: BTreeSet<Point> = BTreeSet::new(); 
//  for i in 0..4 {
//      let i = i as f64;
//      for j in 0..4 {
//          let j = j as f64; 
//          points.insert(Point::new(i, j));
//      }
//  }
    assert_eq!((&points).len(), 16);
    let hull = convex_hull_naive(&points); 
    let hull_should_be = btreeset!(
        Point::new(0.0, 0.0),
        Point::new(1.0, 0.0),
        Point::new(2.0, 0.0),
        Point::new(3.0, 0.0),
        Point::new(3.0, 1.0),
        Point::new(3.0, 2.0),
        Point::new(3.0, 3.0),
        Point::new(2.0, 3.0),
        Point::new(1.0, 3.0),
        Point::new(0.0, 3.0),
        Point::new(0.0, 2.0),
        Point::new(0.0, 1.0)
    );
    assert_eq!(hull, hull_should_be);
}


#[test]
fn test_triangle() {
    let p2 = Point::new(0.0, 0.0); 
    let p1 = Point::new(0.0, 1.0); 
    let p0 = Point::new(1.0, 1.0);
    let t = Triangle::new(p0, p1, p2); 
    assert_eq!(t.range_x(), (0.0, 1.0));
    assert_eq!(t.range_y(), (0.0, 1.0));
    assert_eq!(t.p0, p2);
    assert_eq!(t.p1, p1);
    assert_eq!(t.p2, p0);
    // triangle should not contain its vertices
    assert!(!t.contains(p0));
    assert!(!t.contains(p1));
    assert!(!t.contains(p2));
    // triangle should contain points on any side
    assert!(!t.contains(Point::new(0.5, 0.5)));
    assert!(!t.contains(Point::new(0.3, 0.3)));
    assert!(!t.contains(Point::new(0.2, 0.2)));
    assert!(!t.contains(Point::new(0.1, 0.1)));
    assert!(!t.contains(Point::new(0.0, 0.1)));
    assert!(!t.contains(Point::new(0.0, 0.2)));
    assert!(!t.contains(Point::new(0.1, 1.0)));
    assert!(!t.contains(Point::new(0.2, 1.0)));
    assert!(!t.contains(Point::new(0.2, 1.1)));
    // strictly inside the triangle
    assert!(t.contains(Point::new(0.5, 0.51)));
    assert!(t.contains(Point::new(0.5, 0.52)));
    assert!(t.contains(Point::new(0.5, 0.53)));
    let p2 = Point::new(0.0, 0.0); 
    let p1 = Point::new(0.5, 1.0); 
    let p0 = Point::new(1.0, 0.5);
    let t = Triangle::new(p0, p1, p2); 
    assert_eq!(t.range_x(), (0.0, 1.0));
    assert_eq!(t.range_y(), (0.0, 1.0));
    assert_eq!(t.p0, p2);
    assert_eq!(t.p1, p1);
    assert_eq!(t.p2, p0);
}
```

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `unwrap`ping the result of `partial_cmp` means you don't support `NaN`, but the `PartialEq` implementation indicates you do. Which is it?
2. The explicit `panic` saying you don't support `NaN` also indicates that...
3. My biggest suggestion is to create a wrapper around f64 to ensure that number is never `NaN`. Controversial change, probably, but helps you highlight where that error class can occur. I left some `f64` around, mostly for the test uses, but also because I'm not sure if `powi` / `atan2` can produce `NaN`.
4. `Add` / `Sub` could skip `new` as we know the value must already be non-`NaN`.
5. Create a `test` module
6. Split up the tests; giving them good names that explain why one set of assertions is different from another.
7. Use a space after comma in `derive` list.
8. No need to allocate a vector to sort; an array works fine.
9. No need to explictly specify the type of the 3 points vector / array.
10. Can use `sort_by_key` when there's an `Ord` implementation.
11. There's no reason for `contains` to take ownership of `p`; could take reference. Should benchmark to see if it matters.
12. Taking the `recip`rocal is a method.
13. Strange to use bitwise ANDs (`&`) instead of logical (`&&`)...
14. Make assertion match text - `>= 3`.
15. Comment calls a closure a `fn`; that's too confusing. Don't worry about the implementation; code can show that.
16. No need to use `difference` to remove a single value; `remove` works.
17. No need for an explicit type on `p_internal_set`.
18. No need to `clone`; `Point` is `Copy` so you can just dereference.
19. No need to iterate over reference to the created `BTreeSet`.
20. I prefer to specify the `collect` type on the variable.
21. Let inference handle the type inside the collection with `_`.
22. Why not make `angle` return 0 for same point?
23. No need for type hint on `collect` as last line; type of fn defines it.
24. Why convert from a `Vec` anyway?
25. Remove commented code.

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::ops::{Add, Sub, Mul};
use std::collections::BTreeSet;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct DefinitelyANumber(f64);

impl DefinitelyANumber {
    // TODO: Make this a real error
    fn new(v: f64) -> Result<Self, ()> {
        if v.is_nan() {
            Err(())
        } else {
            Ok(DefinitelyANumber(v))
        }
    }

    fn to_f64(&self) -> f64 {
        self.0
    }
}

impl Add for DefinitelyANumber {
    type Output = DefinitelyANumber;
    fn add(self, rhs: DefinitelyANumber) -> DefinitelyANumber {
        DefinitelyANumber(self.0 + rhs.0)
    }
}

impl Sub for DefinitelyANumber {
    type Output = DefinitelyANumber;
    fn sub(self, rhs: DefinitelyANumber) -> DefinitelyANumber {
        DefinitelyANumber(self.0 - rhs.0)
    }
}

impl Mul for DefinitelyANumber {
    type Output = DefinitelyANumber;
    fn mul(self, rhs: DefinitelyANumber) -> DefinitelyANumber {
        DefinitelyANumber(self.0 * rhs.0)
    }
}

impl PartialEq for DefinitelyANumber {
    fn eq(&self, other: &DefinitelyANumber) -> bool {
        self.0 == other.0
    }
}

impl PartialEq<f64> for DefinitelyANumber {
    fn eq(&self, other: &f64) -> bool {
        if other.is_nan() {
            return false;
        }
        self.0 == *other
    }
}

impl Eq for DefinitelyANumber {}

impl PartialOrd for DefinitelyANumber {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &DefinitelyANumber) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl Ord for DefinitelyANumber {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &DefinitelyANumber) -> Ordering {
        self.0.partial_cmp(&other.0).expect("A number that can't be NaN was NaN")
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)]
pub struct Point {
    x: DefinitelyANumber,
    y: DefinitelyANumber,
}

impl Point {
    pub fn new(x: f64, y: f64) -> Point {
        Point {
            x: DefinitelyANumber::new(x).expect("X coordinate cannot be NaN!"),
            y: DefinitelyANumber::new(y).expect("Y coordinate cannot be NaN!"),
        }
    }

    // Euclidean distance
    fn distance(&self, other: &Point) -> f64 {
        ((self.x - other.x).to_f64().powi(2) + (self.y - other.y).to_f64().powi(2)).sqrt()
    }

    // Draw a horizontal line through this point, connect this point with the other, and measure the angle between these two lines.
    fn angle(&self, other: &Point) -> f64 {
        if self == other {
            0.0
        } else {
            (other.y - self.y).to_f64().atan2((other.x - self.x).to_f64())
        }
    }
}

impl Add for Point {
    type Output = Point;
    fn add(self, rhs: Point) -> Point {
        Point {
            x: self.x + rhs.x,
            y: self.y + rhs.y,
        }
    }
}
impl Sub for Point {
    type Output = Point;
    fn sub(self, rhs: Point) -> Point {
        Point {
            x: self.x - rhs.x,
            y: self.y - rhs.y,
        }
    }
}
// dot product
impl Mul for Point {
    type Output = f64;
    fn mul(self, rhs: Point) -> f64 {
        (self.x * rhs.x + self.y * rhs.y).to_f64()
    }
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Debug)]
pub struct Triangle {
    p0: Point,
    p1: Point,
    p2: Point,
}

impl Triangle {
    fn new(p0: Point, p1: Point, p2: Point) -> Triangle {
        // Sort by x-coordinate to make sure the first point is the leftmost and lowest.
        let mut v = [p0, p1, p2];
        v.sort();
        Triangle {
            p0: v[0],
            p1: v[1],
            p2: v[2],
        }
    }

    fn range_x(&self) -> (f64, f64) {
        (self.p0.x.to_f64(), self.p2.x.to_f64())
    }

    fn range_y(&self) -> (f64, f64) {
        let mut v = [self.p0, self.p1, self.p2];
        v.sort_by_key(|v| v.y);
        (v[0].y.to_f64(), v[2].y.to_f64())
    }

    // Barycentric Technique, check whether point is in triangle, see http://blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/
    fn contains(&self, p: Point) -> bool {
        let v0 = self.p2 - self.p0;
        let v1 = self.p1 - self.p0;
        let v2 = p - self.p0;
        let dot00 = v0 * v0;
        let dot01 = v0 * v1;
        let dot02 = v0 * v2;
        let dot11 = v1 * v1;
        let dot12 = v1 * v2;
        let inv_denom = (dot00 * dot11 - dot01 * dot01).recip();
        let u = (dot11 * dot02 - dot01 * dot12) * inv_denom;
        let v = (dot00 * dot12 - dot01 * dot02) * inv_denom;

        (u > 0.0) && (v > 0.0) && (u + v < 1.0)
    }
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! btreeset {
    ($($x: expr),*) => {{
         let mut set = ::std::collections::BTreeSet::new();
         $( set.insert($x); )*
         set
    }}
}

pub fn convex_hull_naive(points: &BTreeSet<Point>) -> BTreeSet<Point> {
    // you must have at least 3 points, otherwise there is no hull
    assert!(points.len() >= 3);
    // Remove just one point from the set
    let minus_one = |p: &Point| {
        let mut subset = points.clone();
        subset.remove(p);
        subset
    };
    // set of points that are marked as internal
    let mut p_internal_set = BTreeSet::new();
    // check permutations of 4 points, check if the fourth point is contained in the triangle
    for p_i in points {
        let minus_i = minus_one(&p_i);
        for p_j in minus_i {
            let minus_j = minus_one(&p_j);
            for p_k in minus_j {
                let minus_k = minus_one(&p_k);
                for p_m in minus_k {
                    if Triangle::new(*p_i, p_j, p_k).contains(p_m) {
                        p_internal_set.insert(p_m);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // set of points that are not internal
    let mut hull: Vec<_> = points.difference(&p_internal_set).cloned().collect();
    // sort by coordinates so that the first point is the leftmost
    hull.sort();
    let head = hull[0];

    // sort by the angle with the first point
    // when that is equal, sort by distance to head
    hull.sort_by(|a, b| {
        let angle_a = head.angle(&a);
        let angle_b = head.angle(&b);
        angle_a.partial_cmp(&angle_b).unwrap()
    });
    hull.into_iter().collect()
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use std::collections::BTreeSet;

    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_point() {
        use std::f64::consts::PI;
        let p1 = Point::new(0.0, 0.0);
        let p2 = Point::new(0.0, 1.0);
        assert_eq!(p1.angle(&p2), PI / 2.0);
        assert_eq!(p1.distance(&p2), 1.0);
        let p1 = Point::new(0.0, 0.0);
        let p2 = Point::new(1.0, 1.0);
        assert_eq!(p1.angle(&p2), PI / 4.0);
        assert_eq!(p1.distance(&p2), 2.0f64.sqrt());
        let p1 = Point::new(0.0, 0.0);
        let p2 = Point::new(1.0, -1.0);
        assert_eq!(p1.angle(&p2), -PI / 4.0);
        assert_eq!(p1.distance(&p2), 2.0f64.sqrt());
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_convex_hull_naive() {
        let points: BTreeSet<_> = (0..4)
            .into_iter()
            .flat_map(move |i| {
                let i = i as f64;
                (0..4).into_iter().map(move |j| {
                    let j = j as f64;
                    Point::new(i, j)
                })
            })
            .collect();
        assert_eq!((&points).len(), 16);
        let hull = convex_hull_naive(&points);
        let hull_should_be = btreeset!(Point::new(0.0, 0.0),
                                       Point::new(1.0, 0.0),
                                       Point::new(2.0, 0.0),
                                       Point::new(3.0, 0.0),
                                       Point::new(3.0, 1.0),
                                       Point::new(3.0, 2.0),
                                       Point::new(3.0, 3.0),
                                       Point::new(2.0, 3.0),
                                       Point::new(1.0, 3.0),
                                       Point::new(0.0, 3.0),
                                       Point::new(0.0, 2.0),
                                       Point::new(0.0, 1.0));
        assert_eq!(hull, hull_should_be);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_triangle() {
        let p2 = Point::new(0.0, 0.0);
        let p1 = Point::new(0.0, 1.0);
        let p0 = Point::new(1.0, 1.0);
        let t = Triangle::new(p0, p1, p2);
        assert_eq!(t.range_x(), (0.0, 1.0));
        assert_eq!(t.range_y(), (0.0, 1.0));
        assert_eq!(t.p0, p2);
        assert_eq!(t.p1, p1);
        assert_eq!(t.p2, p0);
        // triangle should not contain its vertices
        assert!(!t.contains(p0));
        assert!(!t.contains(p1));
        assert!(!t.contains(p2));
        // triangle should contain points on any side
        assert!(!t.contains(Point::new(0.5, 0.5)));
        assert!(!t.contains(Point::new(0.3, 0.3)));
        assert!(!t.contains(Point::new(0.2, 0.2)));
        assert!(!t.contains(Point::new(0.1, 0.1)));
        assert!(!t.contains(Point::new(0.0, 0.1)));
        assert!(!t.contains(Point::new(0.0, 0.2)));
        assert!(!t.contains(Point::new(0.1, 1.0)));
        assert!(!t.contains(Point::new(0.2, 1.0)));
        assert!(!t.contains(Point::new(0.2, 1.1)));
        // strictly inside the triangle
        assert!(t.contains(Point::new(0.5, 0.51)));
        assert!(t.contains(Point::new(0.5, 0.52)));
        assert!(t.contains(Point::new(0.5, 0.53)));
        let p2 = Point::new(0.0, 0.0);
        let p1 = Point::new(0.5, 1.0);
        let p0 = Point::new(1.0, 0.5);
        let t = Triangle::new(p0, p1, p2);
        assert_eq!(t.range_x(), (0.0, 1.0));
        assert_eq!(t.range_y(), (0.0, 1.0));
        assert_eq!(t.p0, p2);
        assert_eq!(t.p1, p1);
        assert_eq!(t.p2, p0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "to make this a real error"?

Comment: @qed something that implements `std::error::Error`. `Result<T, ()>` is a lazy way of saying "the operation can fail but I'm not going to tell you how or why". Not very nice to end users of that method.