# Needleman–Wunsch algorithm in Rust

Tags: algorithm, rust, bioinformatics

The Needleman–Wunsch algorithm is an algorithm used in bioinformatics to align protein or nucleotide sequences. Here is an implementation in Rust:

```
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub enum Direction {
    Match, // go diagonally, left and up
    Left,
    Up,
    Undefined, 
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct ResultEntry {
    pub score: i64,
    pub direction: Direction,
}

impl ResultEntry {
    fn new(s: i64, d: Direction) -> ResultEntry {
        ResultEntry {
            score: s, 
            direction: d,
        }
    }
}

pub trait NeedlemanWunsch<T> {
    fn align(&mut self, vec: &mut Vec<T>, similarity: &Fn(&T, &T) -> i64, gap_penalty: i64) -> (Vec<Option<T>>, Vec<Option<T>>);
}


impl<T> NeedlemanWunsch<T> for Vec<T> where T: Eq + Copy + Clone {
    fn align(&mut self, vec: &mut Vec<T>, similarity: &Fn(&T, &T) -> i64, gap_penalty: i64) -> (Vec<Option<T>>, Vec<Option<T>>) {
        let mut mat = init_align_matrix(self.len() , vec.len());
        fill_align_matrix(&mut mat, self, vec, similarity, gap_penalty);
        let mat = &mat; // no need to mutate mat any more. 
        let mut vec1: Vec<Option<T>> = Vec::new(); 
        let mut vec2: Vec<Option<T>> = Vec::new(); 
        // the dimension of the alignment matrix is one larger than vec1.len by vec2.len
        let mut i = self.len(); 
        let mut j = vec.len(); 
        loop {
            match mat[i][j].direction {
                Direction::Match => {
                    vec1.insert(0, Some(self[i-1]));
                    vec2.insert(0, Some(vec[j-1]));
                    i -= 1; 
                    j -= 1; 
                }, 
                Direction::Left => {
                    vec1.insert(0, None);
                    // the dimension of the alignment matrix is one larger than vec1.len by vec2.len
                    vec2.insert(0, Some(vec[j-1]));
                    j -= 1; 
                }, 
                Direction::Up => {
                    // the dimension of the alignment matrix is one larger than vec1.len by vec2.len
                    vec1.insert(0, Some(self[i-1]));
                    vec2.insert(0, None);
                    i -= 1;
                }, 
                Direction::Undefined => {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return (vec1, vec2);
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_align() {
    fn similarity(c1: &char, c2: &char) -> i64 {
        if c1 == c2 { 1 } else { -1 }
    }
    let mut vec1: Vec<_> = "what".chars().collect();
    let mut vec2: Vec<_> = "white".chars().collect();
    let res = vec1.align(&mut vec2, &similarity, -1);
    let res_should_be = (
        vec![Some('w'), Some('h'), Some('a'), Some('t'), None], 
        vec![Some('w'), Some('h'), Some('i'), Some('t'), Some('e')], 
    );
    assert_eq!(res, res_should_be);
    let mut vec1: Vec<_> = "ab".chars().collect();
    let mut vec2: Vec<_> = "aeb".chars().collect();
    let res = vec1.align(&mut vec2, &similarity, -1);
    let res_should_be = (
        vec![Some('a'), None, Some('b')], 
        vec![Some('a'), Some('e'), Some('b')], 
    );
    assert_eq!(res, res_should_be);
}

type AlignMatrix = Vec<Vec<ResultEntry>>;

/// len1: Length of the first vector, or number of rows for the alignment matrix.
/// len2: Length of the second vector, or number of cols for the alignment matrix.
fn init_align_matrix(len1: usize, len2: usize) -> AlignMatrix {
    let len1 = len1 + 1; 
    let len2 = len2 + 1; 
    // starting point has undefined direction
    let mut mat: AlignMatrix = vec![vec![ResultEntry::new(0, Direction::Undefined); len2]; len1];
    // first row all go left
    for i in 1..len2 {
        mat[0][i] = ResultEntry::new(-(i as i64), Direction::Left);
    }
    // first col all go up
    for i in 1..len1 {
        mat[i][0] = ResultEntry::new(-(i as i64), Direction::Up);
    }
    mat[0][0] = ResultEntry::new(0, Direction::Undefined);
    mat
}

#[test]
fn test_align_mat() {
    let m = init_align_matrix(2, 3); 
    let m_should_be = vec![
        vec![ResultEntry::new( 0, Direction::Undefined), ResultEntry::new(-1, Direction::Left),      ResultEntry::new(-2, Direction::Left),      ResultEntry::new(-3, Direction::Left)],
        vec![ResultEntry::new(-1, Direction::Up),        ResultEntry::new( 0, Direction::Undefined), ResultEntry::new( 0, Direction::Undefined), ResultEntry::new( 0, Direction::Undefined)],
        vec![ResultEntry::new(-2, Direction::Up),        ResultEntry::new( 0, Direction::Undefined), ResultEntry::new( 0, Direction::Undefined), ResultEntry::new( 0, Direction::Undefined)],
    ];
    assert_eq!(m, m_should_be);
}

#[test]
fn test_fill_mat() {
        fn similarity(c1: &char, c2: &char) -> i64 {
            if c1 == c2 {
                1
            } else {
                -1
            }
        }
        let mut vec1: Vec<_>  = "ab".chars().collect();
        let mut vec2: Vec<_>  = "aeb".chars().collect();
        let mut mat = init_align_matrix(vec1.len(), vec2.len());
        fill_align_matrix(&mut mat, &mut vec1, &mut vec2, &similarity, -1);
        use self::Direction::Undefined as ud;
        use self::Direction::Left as lt; 
        use self::Direction::Up as up; 
        use self::Direction::Match as mt;
        let res_should_be = vec![
            vec![ResultEntry::new(0, ud), ResultEntry::new(-1, lt), ResultEntry::new(-2, lt), ResultEntry::new(-3, lt)],
            vec![ResultEntry::new(-1, up), ResultEntry::new(1, mt), ResultEntry::new(0, lt), ResultEntry::new(-1, lt)],
            vec![ResultEntry::new(-2, up), ResultEntry::new(0, up), ResultEntry::new(0, mt), ResultEntry::new(1, mt)],
        ];
        assert_eq!(mat, res_should_be);
}

fn fill_align_matrix<T>(mat: &mut AlignMatrix, vec1: &mut Vec<T>, vec2: &mut Vec<T>, similarity: &Fn(&T, &T) -> i64, gap_penalty: i64) {
    assert_eq!(mat.len(), vec1.len() + 1);
    assert_eq!(mat[0].len(), vec2.len() + 1);

    fn get_score_set_direction<U>(mat: &mut AlignMatrix, vec1: &Vec<U>, vec2: &Vec<U>, similarity: &Fn(&U, &U) -> i64, gap_penalty: i64, i: usize, j: usize) -> i64 {
        if i == 0 || j == 0 {
            mat[i][j].score
        } else if mat[i][j].direction != Direction::Undefined {
            mat[i][j].score
        } else {
            let up_left = get_score_set_direction(mat, vec1, vec2, similarity, gap_penalty, i - 1, j - 1);
            let up      = get_score_set_direction(mat, vec1, vec2, similarity, gap_penalty, i - 1, j);
            let left    = get_score_set_direction(mat, vec1, vec2, similarity, gap_penalty, i, j - 1);
            // the dimension of the alignment matrix is one larger than vec1.len by vec2.len
            let similarity_score = similarity(&vec1[i-1], &vec2[j-1]); 
            let match_score =  up_left + similarity_score; 
            let up_score = up + gap_penalty; 
            let left_score = left + gap_penalty;
            let m = *[match_score, up_score, left_score].iter().max().unwrap();
            #[cfg(feature = "verbose")]
            {
                print_mat(mat);
                println!("Node: {:?}", (i, j));
                println!("up_left, up, left: {:?}", (up_left, up, left));
                println!("Match, up, left: {:?}", (match_score, up_score, left_score));
                println!("Max score: {}", m);
            }
            if m == match_score {
                #[cfg(feature = "verbose")]
                {
                    println!("Go Up and Left!");    
                }
                mat[i][j] = ResultEntry::new(m, Direction::Match);
            } else if m == up_score {
                #[cfg(feature = "verbose")]
                {
                    println!("Go Up!"); 
                }
                mat[i][j] = ResultEntry::new(m, Direction::Up);
            } else {
                #[cfg(feature = "verbose")]
                {
                    println!("Go Left!");   
                }
                mat[i][j] = ResultEntry::new(m, Direction::Left);
            }
            m
        }
    }
    for i in 1..(vec1.len() + 1) {
        for j in 1..(vec2.len() + 1) {
            get_score_set_direction(mat, vec1, vec2, similarity, gap_penalty, i, j);
        }
    }
    #[cfg(feature = "verbose")] 
    {
        print_mat(mat);
    }
}

fn print_mat(mat: &AlignMatrix) {
    use std::fmt::Write; 
    fn direction_to_arrow(d: Direction) -> char {
        match d {
            Direction::Match => '↖', 
            Direction::Up => '↑', 
            Direction::Left => '←', 
            Direction::Undefined => '.', 
        }
    }
    for row in mat {
        let mut s = String::new(); 
        for el in row { 
            write!(&mut s, "{:>4}", el.score).unwrap(); 
        } 
        println!("{}", s);
    }
    for row in mat {
        let mut s = String::new(); 
        for el in row { 
            write!(&mut s, "{:>4}", direction_to_arrow(el.direction)).unwrap(); 
        } 
        println!("{}", s);
    }
}
```

This algorithm is usually applied to a sequence of chars or bytes, here I have generalized to any type of Eq.

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This code exhibits some of the same problems as [your previous submission](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/141742/32521); specifically: *"Let inference handle the type inside the collection with _"* and *"Remove commented code*". If you are going to ignore previous feedback; what benefit do we have to providing more?

Comment: Sorry, I was busy making this thing compile and pass tests. Explicit type annotation does have the benefit of clarity, but I do prefer to saving quite a few keystrokes. Commented codes are now in conditional compilation blocks, because I like to have the option of printing out things when necessary.

Comment: *Sorry, I was busy making this thing compile and pass tests* — We aren't in a hurry to review your code, forcing you to post it before it's ready ^_^. Make it compile, then take your time to make it good. Once you've finished making it as good as you can, then it's a good time for external review.